# How do I get package update notifications on login?

Tags: 11.10, server, command-line, ssh, remote-access

In Ubuntu 11.04 Server when I would log in via ssh it would tell me how many packages are available for updating in the welcome message.  After upgrading to 11.10 I no longer get that information.  Is there a package I need to install or a config file that needs changing?

**11.04 output:**

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 11.10 (GNU/Linux 3.0.0-12-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

32 packages can be updated.
8 updates are security updates.

Last login: Mon Nov 21 16:19:01 2011 from han-solo.local
```

**11.10 output:**

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 11.10 (GNU/Linux 3.0.0-12-server x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/serverguide/C
No mail.
Last login: Tue Nov 22 19:07:19 2011 from han-solo.local
```

Answer (score 1):

There probably are simply no updates available for installation. I recommend checking:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

(Please note that it is possible that there *are* updates available, but that they only recently became available, and were not seen before running `sudo apt-get update`. If you want to know for sure if the reason you're not being notified of updates is because there are none available, then you should run `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` *before* running `sudo apt-get update`. But it's advisable to then cancel rather than accepting the updates--if there are any--and run `sudo apt-get update` before actually updating.)

Comment: The welcome banner is also only updated once per day.  You may need to wait a few days to be sure it is not working correctly.